# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'chargesName' cannot be found on null

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

> My project based on spring boot,Thymeleaf,mysql,html and Jquery.

**My scenario** 
is to Get the List iterate and show the data in the table 1st column in the HTML and post the data (html-chargesName and input amount)  which is getting from the dynamic input fields and save it into related columns,so it will need to the hit spring boot @RestController.

But I got Thymeleaf ERROR like

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:
>   Property or field 'chargesName' cannot be found on null

**Here is Full Code...**

```js
/**
 * This is for set charges form
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() 
    {
      var amttype = $(this).val();
      if (amttype == 1) 
      {
        $("#amt1").show();
        $("#amt2").hide();
        $("#amt3").hide();
        
      } 
      else if (amttype == 2) 
      {
         $("#amt1").hide();
         $("#amt2").show();
         $("#amt3").hide();
      } 
      else if (amttype == 3) 
      {
         $("#amt1").hide();
         $("#amt2").hide();
         $("#amt3").show();
      }
      else {
         $("#amt1").hide();
         $("#amt2").hide();
         $("#amt3").hide();
      }
      
    });
 
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
     <!-- bootstrap css lib --> 
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <!-- Bootstrap/Jquery CDN library files -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <!-- External JQuery Script -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/formjs/setchargesform.js"></script>
     
    <!-- Body Content Goes Here --> 
      <div class="container">
     <form method="post" th:object="${entSetCharges}" th:action="@{/updatesetcharges}">
     <div class="table-responsive"> 
     
     <table class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Charge Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Charge/Unit Type</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="savedcharges:${savedchargeslist}">
          <td>
          <label th:text="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:value="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:field="*{chargesName}"></label>
          </td>
          
          <td>
          <input id="amt1" class="form-control" th:field="*{perFlat}">
          <input id="amt2" class="form-control" th:field="*{perUnit}">
          <input id="amt3" class="form-control" th:field="*{perSqrft}">
          </td>
          
          <td>
      <select id="societyname" class="form-control" th:field="*{tempunitType}">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">perFlat</option>
      <option value="2">perUnit</option>
      <option value="3">perSqrft</option>
      </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        
     </table>
     </div>
     
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warn">Reset</button>
     </form>
     </div>
     <!-- Body content finishes -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

**@RestController**

```
@GetMapping(value="/setchargeslist")
    public ModelAndView doGetSetchargesList()
    {
        List<EntSetCharges> listCharges = new ArrayList<>();
        ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView("SetCharges");
        try {
            /*Get the set charges list*/
            listCharges = serSetCharges.doGetSetChargesList();
            if(listCharges!=null)
            {
            respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",listCharges);
            }
            else
            {
                respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",new ArrayList<>());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return respondResult;
    }
```

**ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="setcharges")
public class EntSetCharges implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3827507518731160293L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="pksetcharges")
    private int pkSetCharges;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String chargesName;
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    private int perFlat;
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    private double perUnit;
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    private double perSqrft;

    @Version
    private int version;
    private Boolean is_active;
    private String created_by;
    private Date created_ts;
    private String modified_by;
    private Date modified_ts;
    private String approved_by;
    private Date approved_ts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the form at the top of your html page:

```
<form method="post" th:object="${entSetCharges}" th:action="@{/updatesetcharges}">
```

The `th:field="*{chargesName}` is bound to the object/bean inside your  `th:object="${entSetCharges}`. Meaning that you are searching for a `chargesName` field inside your `entSetCharges` object which does not exist or is null.

**Solution:**

- <s>Maybe change your `th:field="*{chargesName}"` to `${savedcharges.chargesName}` expression to access your object's field.</s>
- Try adding `respondResult.addObject("entSetCharges",new EntSetCharges());` above your return line. Your view **doesn't** automatically create this object for you.

Comment: savedcharges.chargesName is getting from EntAssignCharges but i need to store it into EntSetCharges,unfortunately both are having same column names ".chargesName"..

Comment: ERROR:: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "entSetCharges.chargesName" (template: "SetCharges" - line 33, col 91)

Comment: Error 2: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'chargesName' cannot be found on null

Comment: Can you try adding an new EntSetCharges object to your model? Like so: `respondResult.addObject("entSetCharges",new EntSetCharges());` and tell me what happened

Comment: no i just tried null check for that..i searched for this same error reg,so i tried this solution...so nothing about it..

Comment: I mean add `respondResult.addObject("entSetCharges",new EntSetCharges());` before your return statement

Answer (score 0):

I init the entity object like **respondResult.addObject("entSetCharges",new EntSetCharges());**

```
@GetMapping(value="/setchargeslist")
    public ModelAndView doGetSetchargesList()
    {
        List<EntSetCharges> listCharges = new ArrayList<>();
        ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView("SetCharges");
        try {
            /*Get the set charges list*/
            listCharges = serSetCharges.doGetSetChargesList();
            if(listCharges!=null)
            {
            respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",listCharges);
            respondResult.addObject("entSetCharges",new EntSetCharges());
            }
            else
            {
                respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",new ArrayList<>());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return respondResult;
    }
```