# How to post a List of Entity type data using Thymeleaf?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

> My project based on spring boot,Thymeleaf,mysql,html and Jquery.

**Scenario**
My scenario is POST a List of EntSetCharges Data using Thyemeleaf and hitting the Spring boot @RestController.
Previously i worked with this errors [Error 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406346/org-springframework-expression-spel-spelevaluationexception-el1007e-property-o)
[Error 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412988/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-primary-constructor-found-for-java-util-list)
Rightnow got another Error

> 2017-11-22 14:58:19.717 ERROR 1420 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: **"tempEntSetChargesList[0].chargesName" (template: "SetCharges" - line 37, col 91)]** with root cause
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1025E: The collection has '0' elements, index '0' is invalid

The Line Indicates the HTML code is table's 1st column

**th:field="*{tempEntSetChargesList[__${status.index}__].chargesName}"**

I still not succeeded to POST the data to controller..Please Help me out..

[image: This is HTML page]
**Here is Full Codes**

```html
<form id="setchargesformid" method="post" th:object="${wrpSetCharges}" th:action="@{/updatesetcharges}">
 <div class="table-responsive"> 
 
 <table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Charge Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Charge/Unit Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="savedcharges,status:${savedchargeslist}">
     <!--  <td id="colhide" hidden="true">
      <label th:value="${savedcharges.pkSetCharges}" th:field="*{pkSetCharges}" ></label>
      </td> -->
      
      <td>
      <label th:text="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:value="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:field="*{tempEntSetChargesList[__${status.index}__].chargesName}"></label>
      </td>
      
      <td>
      <input id="amt1" class="form-control" th:field="*{tempUnitAmount}">
      </td>
      
      <td>
  <select id="societyname" class="form-control" th:field="*{tempunitType}" >
  <option value="perFlat" selected="selected">perFlat</option>
  <option value="perUnit">perUnit</option>
  <option value="perSqrft">perSqrft</option>
  </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
 </table>
 </div>
 
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warn">Reset</button>
 </form>
```

**@RestController**

### 1St hits the [localhost:8080/setchargeslist](http://localhost:8080/setchargeslist)

```
@GetMapping(value="/setchargeslist")
    public ModelAndView doGetSetchargesList()
    {
        List<EntSetCharges> listCharges = new ArrayList<>();
        ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView("SetCharges");
        try {
            /*Get the set charges list*/
            listCharges = serSetCharges.doGetSetChargesList();
            if(listCharges!=null)
            {
            respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",listCharges);
            //respondResult.addObject("tempEntSetChargesList",new EntSetCharges());
            respondResult.addObject("wrpSetCharges",new WrpSetCharges());
            }
            else
            {
                respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",new ArrayList<>());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return respondResult;
    }
```

---

**While clicking the Submit Button it will hits to [/updatesetcharges](http://localhost:8080/updatesetcharges)**

```
@PostMapping(value="/updatesetcharges")
public ModelAndView doUpdateSetCharges(@ModelAttribute WrpSetCharges wrpSetCharges)
{
    ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView();
    try {
        List<EntSetCharges> entSetChargesList = new ArrayList<>();
    Boolean result = serSetCharges.doUpdateSetCharges(entSetChargesList);
} catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return respondResult;
    }
```

---

This is a wrapper class

```
 public class WrpSetCharges {

        private List<EntSetCharges> tempEntSetChargesList = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<EntSetCharges> getTempEntSetChargesList() {
            return tempEntSetChargesList;
        }

        public void setTempEntSetChargesList(List<EntSetCharges> tempEntSetChargesList) {
            this.tempEntSetChargesList = tempEntSetChargesList;
        }
      }
```

Comment: There is a similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500731/how-to-bind-an-object-list-with-thymeleaf. Try to use wrapper in you post form. i.e <tr th:each="savedcharges,status:${wrpSetCharges.savedchargeslist}">. Like in the example

Comment: i tried buddy,but still facing error..i dont know where my code strucks..even tough the th:feild as per syntax..but not working..pls help me

Comment: u can also check my ERROR Links given in this post...

Comment: I could not see where tempEntSetChargesList is initialised ? User savedchargeslist instead in th:field

Comment: u can see i my code @GetMapping(value="/setchargeslist"),,which is  tempEntSetChargesList  is commented but wrapper class is initalized..Inside the wrapper class is having tempEntSetChargesList

Comment: Did you try to  <label th:text="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:value="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:field="*{savedchargeslist[__${status.index}__].chargesName}"></label>

Comment: u told to make without underscore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159568/discussion-between-aliaksei-stadnik-and-vignesh-r).

Comment: i still not find answers..please help me guys..

Comment: please give me a help guys....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind an object list with thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500731/how-to-bind-an-object-list-with-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: the cause of the exception is

**"org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException‌​: EL1025E:(pos 10): The collection has '0' elements, index '0' is invalid"**

Simply add an th:if condition if the team.users can have zero elements.