# Using Jquery How to retrive input data from thymeleaf generated table?

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot

> My project based on spring boot,Thymeleaf,mysql,html and Jquery.

i showing data using thyemeleaf **th:each** in html table,but my scenario is i am going to update table data using Input box in Amount col and drop-down in Charge/unit type col,..

[image: My page look like this...]

When i click submit button, i need to retrive the list of values in object type.i dont know how to achive this in Jquery..

> i already tried to submit form using in THYMELEAF,but i am not able to achive..any one
>   knows how to achive this is **JQUERY** is also help full for
>   me..

HERE is **old post Reg THYMELEAF Form Posting** [Thymeleaf Stackoverflow Link click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431420/how-to-post-a-list-of-entity-type-data-using-thymeleaf)
please help me ..Thanks in advance

Here is my codes..

```html
<form id="setchargesformid" action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/updatesetcharges}">
 <div class="table-responsive"> 
 
 <table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Charge Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Charge/Unit Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="savedcharges:${savedchargeslist}">
      <td id="colhide" hidden="true">
      <label th:value="${savedcharges.pkSetCharges}" name="pk"></label>
      </td> 
      
      <td>
      <label th:value="${savedcharges.chargesName}" th:text="${savedcharges.chargesName}" name="chargenames"></label>
      </td>
      
      <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amounts">
      </td>
      
      <td>
  <select class="form-control" name="unit">
  <option value="perFlat">perFlat</option>
  <option value="perUnit">perUnit</option>
  <option value="perSqrft">perSqrft</option>
  </select>
      </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
 </table>
 </div>
 
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warn">Reset</button>
 </form>
```

> "/setchargeslist" is used to Sending Values to HTML page to show in
>   table ChargesName column

**@RestController**

```
@GetMapping(value="/setchargeslist")
public ModelAndView doGetSetchargesList()
{
    List<EntSetCharges> listCharges = new ArrayList<>();
    ModelAndView respondResult = new ModelAndView("SetCharges");
    try {
        /*Get the set charges list*/
        listCharges = serSetCharges.doGetSetChargesList();
        if(listCharges!=null)
        {
        respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",listCharges);

        ArrayList<EntSetCharges> tempEntSetChargesList = new ArrayList<>();
        //tempEntSetChargesList.add(new EntSetCharges());
        respondResult.addObject("tempEntSetChargesList",tempEntSetChargesList);

        //respondResult.addObject("wrpSetCharges",new WrpSetCharges());
        }
        else
        {
            respondResult.addObject("savedchargeslist",new ArrayList<>());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return respondResult;
}
```

---

Submit button hits this **/updatesetcharges** controller

```
@PostMapping(value="/updatesetcharges")
public ModelAndView doUpdateSetCharges(@RequestBody  ArrayList<EntSetCharges> tempEntSetChargesList)throws IOException
{
     // logic behind for mapping each values to column
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="setcharges")
public class EntSetCharges implements Serializable
{

@Transient
private String tempunitType;

@Transient
private String tempUnitAmount;

@Transient
private LogEntSetCharges tempLogEntSetCharges;
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i accept your advice buddy..sure i will correct it.but problem is experience.i am only have 1 year experience in JSF but not in any scripting languages like jquery,thymeleaf etc..for this above question i need for refernces links,and ideas only.not need entire code for that....Thats why posted my older post links also..i did not get any proper help for thymeleaf..so kndly understand my situation.Thank You buddy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post a List of Entity type data using Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431420/how-to-post-a-list-of-entity-type-data-using-thymeleaf)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47431420/4068240

Comment: ha ha that post is also mine buddy..but only specifically for thymeleaf..but this post is for jquery.But also need for thymeleaf.in that post does not have a answers till..please help me buddy

Comment: _haha that post is also mine buddy.._ so you&#39;re telling me you duplicate your own posts? Also, did you consider that calling others randomly _&quot;buddy&quot;_ could offend them?

Comment: ok ..so sorry..@Clijsters

Comment: please sir help me,i need to solve this issue.Thanks for reply

Comment: This post is mainly focused on Jquery.not a duplicate only.@Clijsters sir